# ElasticSearch relational querying?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two ES documents (as examples):

```
{
    "id": "person_1",
    "name": "John"
}

{
    "id": "organisation",
    "employeesById": [ "person_1" ]
}
```

Is it possible to do a query which returns all organisations which have an employee with the name 'John' or do I have to denormalise the data structure above and do a employeesById.employee.name?

Comment: Do the two documents belong to the same index? If so, you should have a look at the join datatype https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/parent-join.html

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your use case, I'd suggest you trying to denormalize. E.g.,

```
{
  "id": "person_1",
  "name": "John",
  "organisation": "organisation_id"
}
```

If (1) both documents are stored into the same index and (2) a person changes organisation very often, keeping the denormalised documents consistent would be more demanding (lots of related documents to retrieve and update). In this case, I would suggest defining the relation person-organisation by using a Join datatype ([link to Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html)) and using the parent-join queries to run your searches ([link to Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html)).